# C++/CLI managed wrapper around C static library

Tags: c++-cli

Help!

I'm totally exhausted/frustrated with what seems to be a reasonably easy task. I’m not sure what I'm doing wrong; let alone if I'm doing it correct. I'm "required" to use an existing library (a C static library – over 100,000 lines of straight C code) in developing a WPF application (VS 2010, C# 4.0). Oh, and I can't touch the existing C code - use it as is!

I've read so many postings (advanced topics, how-to, etc), yet I'm so new to C++/CLI that it's just not making sense. From what I've read the best approach is to wrap the C static library as follows:

> Unmanaged C static library <---> C++/CLI managed wrapper DLL <--->
>   managed WPF application

This is the stripped down C header file:

```
/* Call this function to execute a command. */
int issue_command(int command, long param1, long param2);

/* Completion call back function; you must supply a definition. */
extern  int command_completed(int command, long param1, long param2);

struct struct_command_str
{
      char   command_str[10];
      char   param1_st[2];
      char   param2_st[2];
      char   success;
};

/* You must supply definitions to the following extern items. */
extern  int command_status;
extern struct struct_command_str  command_str;
```

**The problem(s):**

What I can’t seem to do correctly is provide a C++/CLI implementation for the call back functions, and the two extern items (`command_status` and struct `command_str`).

Can someone provide a sample C++/CLI implementation for the above missing call back functions and externs?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Can you include at least one failed attempt at the C++/CLI implementation?

Answer (score 3):

in your C++/CLI managed wrapper project, add 2 files :

a .c file :

```
extern void doSomething();

int command_status = 0;

struct_command_str command_str = { "command1", "p1", "p2", 't' };

int command_completed(int command, long param1, long param2) {
    ...
    command_status = 1;
    ...
    doSomething();
    ...
    command_status = 2;
    ...
    return 3;
}
```

a cpp file

```
void doSomethingManagedWrapper() {
    ...
    call managed code
    ...
}

void doSomething() {
    doSomethingManagedWrapper();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you implement these in your c++/cli module, use the same signature shown in the c header file,but prefixed with `extern "C"`.

also put an `extern "C"` block around the `#include` of the C header file.

Comment: Rolo's comment above seemed to resolve the issues. I never had to try your suggestion, but appreciate the information (tuck away for future use).